# Python: need to scrape data in table that will expand with lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I want t get quarter result Profit Attb. to SH ('000) from http://klse.i3investor.com/servlets/stk/fin/8982.jsp

```
<b>Quarter Result:</b><br/> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="nc" width="100%"> <tr> <th class="left">F.Y.</th> <th class="left">Quarter</th> <th class="right">Revenue ('000)</th> <th class="right">Profit before Tax ('000)</th> <th class="right">Profit ('000)</th> <th class="right">Profit Attb. to SH ('000)</th> <th class="right">EPS (Cent)</th> <th class="right">DPS (Cent)</th> <th class="right">NAPS</th> <th class="center" width="33"></th> </tr>  <tr> <td class="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 2016-12-31 </td> <td class="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 2016-09-30 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 79,082 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 14,376 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 10,692 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 10,398 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 3.37 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 0.00 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 1.5100 </td> <td class="center" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> <a href="" onclick="viewFinancialSource('62459');return false;" title="View Source"> <img class="sp view16" src="http://cdn1.i3investor.com/cm/icon/trans16.gif" width="16px;" alt="View Source"/> </a> 
 <span class="hide" id="financialSourceTitle62459"> Quarter: 2016-09-30 </span> <span class="hide" id="financialSourceDetail62459">  <p> <a target="_blank" href ="/servlets/staticfile/290836.jsp"> <img src="http://cdn1.i3investor.com/cm/icon/file-download-small.png" width="16px" height="16px" alt="3rd Q2016_CGB.PDF"/> 3rd Q2016_CGB.PDF </a> </p>  </span>  </td> </tr>  <tr> <td class="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 2016-12-31 </td> <td class="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 2016-06-30 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 51,277 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 7,050 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 5,364 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 5,068 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 1.64 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 0.00 </td> <td class="right" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> 1.4800 </td> <td class="center" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"> <a href="" onclick="viewFinancialSource('56288');return false;" title="View Source"> <img class="sp view16" src="http://cdn1.i3investor.com/cm/icon/trans16.gif" width="16px;" alt="View Source"/> </a>
```

Example, there are annual result table and quarter result table, I only want data from the last two quarters for Profit Attb. to SH ('000) whihc is 10,398 and 5,068 
[image]

However, the table is expanding every quarter. I would like have a robust way to retrieve data using lxml, with xpath or cssselect. So that, when the next quarter data coming, my code still working.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://klse.i3investor.com/servlets/stk/fin/8982.jsp')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
output = tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"nc")]/text()')
```

but return blanks ['','','','']

Comment: What have you attempted to so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: @James, add the code that is fail to return results desire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **indexes** and **position()**:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get("http://klse.i3investor.com/servlets/stk/fin/8982.jsp")
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

profit_attb_to_sh = [x.strip() for x in tree.xpath('//table[2]/tr[position()>1 and position()<=3]/td[@class="right"][4]/text()')]

print '\n'.join(profit_attb_to_sh)
```

> **table[2]** means:
>   you'll get the second table from the DOM.
>
> **tr[position()>1 and position()<=3]** means: you'll get every **tr** in that index range (2 and 3). Excluding the first one because it contains the headers.
>
> **td[@class="right"][4]** means: you'll get the fourth **td** from each one of those **tr** that matched the above rule.
>
> Please remember that XPath indexes start from 1 (and not from 0)

**Result:**

```
10,398
5,068
```

**PS:**

You could change:

```
profit_attb_to_sh = [x.strip() for x in tree.xpath('//table[2]/tr[position()>1 and position()<=3]/td[@class="right"][4]/text()')]
```

for:

```
profit_attb_to_sh = map(lambda x: x.strip(), tree.xpath('//table[2]/tr[position()>1 and position()<=3]/td[@class="right"][4]/text()'))
```